# Why this weird output with truncate and BigDecimal?

Tags: java, double, bigdecimal

I am calling a truncate method to truncate the double value so that there should be a single digit after decimal (without rounding off),
For Ex. `truncate(123.48574) = 123.4`.

My truncate method is something like this

```
public double truncate (double x) {
    long y = (long) (x * 10);
    double z = (double) (y / 10);
    return z;
}
```

Its working just fine for almost all the values except for this weird output.

```
double d = 0.787456;
d = truncate(d + 0.1); //gives 0.8 as expected. Okay.
```

But,

```
double d = 0.7;
d = truncate(d + 0.1); //should also give 0.8. But its giving 0.7 only. 
                       //Strange I don't know why?
```

Infact it works fine for all other 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, - , 0.8, 0.9
I mean for example,

```
double d = 0.8;
d = truncate(d + 0.1); //gives 0.9 as expected
```

I tried it with `BigDecimal` too. But the same. No change.
Here is the code for that.

```
double d = 0.7;
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(d + 0.1);
BigDecimal floored = a.setScale(1, BigDecimal.ROUND_DOWN);
double d1 = floored.doubleValue();
System.out.println(d1); //Still gives 0.7
```

And again the real fact is that it works fine with `Math.round`.

```
public double roundUp1d (double d) {
    return Math.round(d * 10.0) / 10.0;
}
```

So if I call `roundUp1d(0.7 + 0.1)`, it gives 0.8 as expected. But I don't want the values to be rounded off so I can't use this.

Whats the problem with 0.7 ?

Comment: I have tested it, If your input is 0.7+0.1, then it will be calculated badly to 0.799999999999999

Comment: But this doesn't happen with all other doubles - 0.1, 0.2 ..etc

Comment: Double values are inaccurate. You should think about using BigDecimal instead.

Comment: I tried it with `BigDecimal` too. But the same. No change. See my updated post.

Comment: 0.7 cannot be accurately represented in a double, so a BigDecimal converted to double may still exhibit the same "problem". Are you aware of the basic problem? Required link: [What every programmer should know about Floating Point](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: What happens when you do `new BigDecimal(0.7).add(new BigDecimal(0.1))`? Your current `BigDecimal` code wouldn't work because `d + 0.1` is still a regular `double` addition which gives you the floating point anomaly. *Btw it's spelt weird not weired.*

Comment: @ADTC So what could be the alternative for that? And thanks for pointing out the spell mistake. I corrected it.

Comment: See the first sentence of my previous comment. What happens when you try that (the `add` method) instead of `d + 0.1`?

Comment: @ADTC I tried that one `new BigDecimal(0.7).add(new BigDecimal(0.1))`. But the same. No change.

Comment: @user1612078 use `System.out.println(new BigDecimal("0.7").add(new BigDecimal("0.1")));` and read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29

Comment: You did set the return value of `add` to `BigDecimal a =` right? The method will not modify the object it is called on as they are immutable.

Comment: @Tom Yeah. this works. But I want to collect it in a variable. No meaning in printing.

Comment: @user1612078 Well, then store it in a variable. `BigDecimal result = new BigDecimal("0.7").add(new BigDecimal("0.1"));`

Comment: Ah yes, thanks to @Tom. It should be `BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.valueOf(d).add(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1));`. This will internally convert the doubles to strings (you don't need to externally convert as per Tom's suggestion).

Comment: @ADTC Previously I did `BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(0.7); BigDecimal b = a.add(new BigDecimal(0.1));`, Then as u suggested in recent post, I changed it to `BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(0.7); a.add(new BigDecimal(0.1));`. So now its giving 0.6 as the output.

Comment: Finally this works. Relief :) Thanks ADTC and TOM. You people are awesome.

Comment: I still suggest you use `BigDecimal.valueOf` instead of the constructor. What is your working solution?

Comment: @ADTC Yeah I used what u suggested `BigDecimal.valueOf`. This is working fine for atleast 0.7. Will this work for all such anomalies of floating point ?

Comment: *Will this work for all...?* **Yes!** That is indeed the whole point of using BigDecimal :) but you need to use it correctly. Simply mentioning it in your code does not constitute correct usage. I will post an answer. I have also learnt while trying to teach :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Floating points are inherently inaccurate by their design. Other answers here already explain the theory behind this inaccuracy. It is highly recommended that you use `BigDecimal` and `BigInteger` instead.

In my answer I want to elaborate on how you are using `BigDecimal` wrongly and how you can use it correctly. Don't make the mistake of simply using these classes as a wrapper for floating point calculations. In your present code:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(d + 0.1);
```

Even though you are trying to use `BigDecimal` here, you are still performing the addition using regular floating point calculations. This is exactly the same as doing:

```
double d_a = d + 0.1; //0.799999999 ad infinitum
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(d_a);
```

To take advantage of the accuracy of the `BigX` classes, you must use their own calculation methods, as well as the `valueOf` static method (not the constructor):

```
BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.valueOf(d).add( BigDecimal.valueOf(0.1) );
```

Here, two `BigDecimal` objects are created to match exactly **0.7** and **0.1**, then the `add` method is used to calculate their sum and produce a third `BigDecimal` object (which will be **0.8** exactly).

Using the `valueOf` static method instead of the constructor ensures the created `BigDecimal` object represents the exact `double` value as it is shown when converted to a string (0.7 as a string is "0.7"), rather than the approximate value stored by the computer to represent it (the computer stores 0.7 as 0.699999999 ad infinitum).

Answer (score 7):

(If you are not interested in theory, scroll to end, theres the fix for your code)

The reason is quite simple: As you know the binary system only supports `0`s and `1`s

So, let's look at your values, and what they are in binary representation:

```
0.1 - 0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
0.2 - 0.001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
0.3 - 0.010011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011
0.4 - 0.01100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
0.5 - 0.1
0.6 - 0.10011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011
0.7 - 0.1011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011
0.8 - 0.1100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
0.9 - 0.11100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101
```

What does that mean? `0.1` is a 10th of 1. No big deal in the *decimal* system, simply shift the separator one position. But in binary you **cannot** express 0.1 - cause every shift of the decimal sign equals `*2` or `/2` - depending on the direction. (And 10 cannot be divided into X shifts of 2)

For values you want to divide by multiples of 2 - you get an EXACT result:

```
1/2 - 0.1
1/4 - 0.01
1/8 - 0.001
1/16- 0.0001
and so on.
```

Therefore trying to calculate a `/10` is an *infinite long* result, which is truncated when the value runs out of bits.

This said, it is a limitation of the way computers work, that such a value can never be stored with full precision.

Site Note: This "fact" has been ignored with the *Patriot System* causing it to become unusable after some hours of operating time, see here: http://sydney.edu.au/engineering/it/~alum/patriot_bug.html

---

*But why does it work for every thing but 0.7 + 0.1* - you might ask

If you test your code with `0.8` - it works - but not with `0.7 + 0.1`.

Again, in binary both values are already imprecise. If you sum up both values, the result 
is even more imprecise, leading to a wrong result:

If you sum up 0.7 and 0.1 (after the decimal separator) you get this:

```
  0.101100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001 1000
+ 0.000110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100 1101
  ---------------------------------------------------------
  0.110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110 0101
```

But 0.8 would be

```
  0.110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110 1000
```

Compare the last 4 bits and note, that the resulting "0.8" of the ADDITION is smaller than if you would convert `0.8` to binary directly.

Guess what:

```
System.out.println(0.7 + 0.1 == 0.8); //returns false
```

When working with numbers you should set yourself a limit of precision - and ALWAYS round numbers accordingly to avoid such errors (not truncate!):

```
 //compare doubles with 3 decimals
 System.out.println((lim(0.7, 3) + lim(0.1, 3)) == lim(0.8, 3)); //true

 public static long lim(double d, int t){
     return Math.round(d*10*t);
 }
```

---

To have your code fixed: round it to 4 digits, before truncating after the first digit:

```
public static double truncate(double x){
   long y = (long)((Math.round(x*10000)/10000.0)*10);
   double z = (double)y/10;
   return z;
}

System.out.println(truncate(0.7+0.1)); //0.8
System.out.println(truncate(0.8)); //0.8
```

This will still truncate as desired but ensures, that a `0.69999` will be rounded to `0.7` before truncating it. You can set the precision as required for your application. 10, 20 ,30, 40 digits?

Other values will still remain correct, because something like `0.58999` will just be rounded to 0.59 - so still truncated as `0.5` and not rounded to `0.6`

Comment: will the fixed code work for all such anomalies of floating numbers? Because If it can happen with 0.7, it can happen with any arbitrary floating number. I mean its unpredictable.

Comment: @user1612078 It will fix the issue for ALL numbers according to the precision you choose. If you decide to ignore anything 20 places behind the decimal separator, then it will produce wrong results, if a number differs from another starting at 21 places behind the separator.

Answer (score 4):

This is not caused by your program nor by Java. Simply, floating point numbers are inaccurate by design. You don't get to know which numbers will be inaccurate, but some will (0.7 in your case). One of the many articles on this subject: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-are-floating-point-calculations-so-inaccurate.htm

Bottom line: never trust that a double 0.7 is REALLY 0.7.

Comment: But I tried the same with `Math.round` and its giving me the expected result. See my updated post.

Comment: In that last attempt, you are still getting `0.699999..` but `println` also rounds the output.

Comment: This is a very common issue and I've never found the ultimate solution to it. A couple more pointers that perhaps could help you: http://mydevelopedworld.wordpress.com/2013/05/19/java-avoid-double-and-float-types-when-accuracy-is-required/ and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16133520/how-to-actually-avoid-floating-point-errors-when-you-need-to-use-float

Comment: Surely you mean 0.7, not 7.0?

Answer (score 3):

The 'problem' lies with using floating point number like `double` or `float`. These numbers use base 2 fractions internally to approximate a large range of numbers, from the very small to the very large.

So for example, `0.5` can be represented as `1/2`, and `0.75` as `1\2 + 1\4`.

However, as you discovered you can't always easily convert between base 10 fractions and base 2 fractions.

Where in base 10 `0.7` is equal to `7/10`, in a base 2 fraction this becomes very difficult.

This is like trying to accurately represent `1/3` in a base 10 decimal number, which is very easy in a base 3 fraction, you can get a very close approximation, as long as you have enough decimal places available, however you cannot accurately represent `1/3` in a base 10 decimal number.

Answer (score 3):

The key point is that float and double are designed to work with a rounding philosophy. If the result of a calculation cannot be represented exactly, the result will be as close as possible to the exact answer, regardless of whether that makes it smaller or larger than exact.

The problem with `0.7 + 0.1` is that 0.79999999999999993338661852249060757458209991455078125, the closest representable value to the sum of 0.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875 and 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625, the representable numbers closest to 0.7 and 0.1, is slightly smaller than 0.8.

There are a couple of possible solutions. If decimal truncation is central to the problem, and more important than performance and space, use BigDecimal. If not, consider adding a small adjustment to account for this effect before truncating. In effect, treat numbers very slightly smaller than 0.8 as being greater than or equal to 0.8. This can work, because the differences introduced by `double` arithmetic are typically much smaller than differences that arise and matter in the real world.

Answer (score 2):

Java uses IEEE 754 format to encode double values.

So that means that each number is an approximation as accurate as possible.

0.7 is bestly approximated by 0.699999999999999999999999

Check this out: http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=048046055

To fix your problem, can you try multiplying by 10.0 and treat your values accordingly?