# Preserve maximum precision for intermediate results when dividing BigDecimals

Tags: java, precision, division, bigdecimal

I do a couple of calculations with `BigDecimal`, before I return the final result. My calculations contain two divisions. I'm aware of the fact that I should define a scale and rounding mode when calling `divide()`. However, since I'm working with currencies, I want to preserve maximum precision as long as possible and **only round my final result** to two decimal places.

What scale and rounding mode should I apply to **intermediate** results for maximum precision?

Comment: Unless you need more than 15 digits of precision, I would use `double` and round the result at the end.  Using `double` is much simpler to code and faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually in physics we take one more digit for intermediate results.

Comment: This sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 4):

Let's suppose, you do something like (a / b) / c.

I would not calculate (a / b) first. I would rather restructure this into

a / (b * c)

It does not only make intermediary rounding unnecessary, it would be more optimal as well.

(a / b) / c = a / (b * c)

Proof:

(a / b) / c = (a * b^-1) * c^-1 = a * (b^-1 * c^-1) = a * 1 / (b * c) = a / (b * c)

Comment: This is a smart approach. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I found a helpful website with examples, explanations, and results of providing precision using BigDecimal.  It's a quick read.

It show various ways of performing the calculation and provides clear examples: http://java-performance.info/bigdecimal-vs-double-in-financial-calculations/

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think any specific answer to your question would probably require some further details on how accurate you need the final results, especially when you are rounding at the end.

I personally would attempt to remove the issue completely and use some form of `Rational` object.

[How to actually avoid floating point errors when you need to use float?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16133520/823393) may be of some help.